# How do I iterate over a json object that has a list of dictionaries inside in Python?

Tags: python

How can I iterate over this to get get MerchantRequestID, CheckoutRequestID, ResultCode, ResultDesc, and all the value in the 'item' list for instance value for PhoneNumber.
Am getting this data from a callBackURl after a user makes a payment.

````
    "Body":{
      "stkCallback":{
        "MerchantRequestID":"19465-780693-1",
        "CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_27072017154747416",
        "ResultCode":0,
        "ResultDesc":"The service request is processed successfully.",
        "CallbackMetadata":{
          "Item":[
            {
              "Name":"Amount",
              "Value":1
            },
            {
              "Name":"MpesaReceiptNumber",
              "Value":"LGR7OWQX0R"
            },
            {
              "Name":"Balance"
            },
            {
              "Name":"TransactionDate",
              "Value":20170727154800
            },
            {
              "Name":"PhoneNumber",
              "Value":254721566839
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }```

I want to get MerchantRequestID, CheckoutRequestID, ResultCode, ResultDesc, and all the value in the list  
'item' then store them in the db.
```new_user = MpesaResponses(MerchantRequestID=data[0]['Body']['stkCallback']['MerchantRequestID'],
                             CheckoutRequestID=data[0]['Body']['stkCallback']['CheckoutRequestID'],
                             ResultCode=data[0]['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultCode'],
                             ResultDesc=data[0]['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultDesc'],
                              Amount=data[0]['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item'][0] 
                              ['value'],
                              MpesaReceiptNumber=data[0]['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata'] 
                              ['Item'][1]['value'],
                              TransactionDate=data[0]['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item'] 
                              [3]['value'],
                              PhoneNumber=data[0]['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item'][4] 
                          ['value'])
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()```
This is what I had tried.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is just a dictionary starting at `"Body"` and not a list containing a dictionary, then just remove the first `[0]` from each variable, then check your spelling on `Value` as so:

```
MerchantRequestID=data['Body']['stkCallback']['MerchantRequestID']
CheckoutRequestID=data['Body']['stkCallback']['CheckoutRequestID']
ResultCode=data['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultCode']
ResultDesc=data['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultDesc']
Amount=data['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item'][0]['Value']
MpesaReceiptNumber=data['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item'][1]['Value']
TransactionDate=data['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item'][3]['Value']
PhoneNumber=data['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item'][4]['Value']
```

Comment: thanks my mistake was the value instead of Value and also the first[0]. I was treating it as a list of dictionary